# Get invoked methods of source code for a statement of a junit test

Tags: java, junit

I want to get the invoked methods(or lines) of source code for a statement in junit test.
The left picture describes this question. Each statement in a junit test invokes some methods in the source code. Therefore, Each statement in the test will have a list of invoked methods.

The reason why I want to get this information is to know that which statement in the test invokes a certain method in the source code. The right picture describes this.

Is there a technique to solve this problem?

[image: List of invoked methods for each statement in junit]
[image: Which statement in the junit test invokes the red method?]

Update

It seems that my question is not clear. I am sorry that I did not explain it well. So I would like to explain more about the question. Here is a coverage example of a junit test.
[image: junit test coverage example]
I want to get a coverage of a specific line such as "acct1.executeTransaction("testCreditsTracking() Test Case", tran1);"
to see if what methods are invoked by this statement. Does eclemma support this?

Comment: This is generally known as Code Coverage.  There are stand-alone tools, although the usual route is a plugin that integrates with an IDE/JUnit test-runner; one example is [EclEmma for Eclipse](http://eclemma.org/).  What's your development environment like?

Comment: Hi! I'm using Eclipse and sublime text. But I want to get method coverage of each line of a junit test not method coverage of a junit test.

Comment: Did you try incrementing a counter each time a method is called? I'm thinking about an object with a static int for each method, and each method increments its own counter.

Comment: @GhostKeepr No, I didn't. Can you explain more? How does it solve my problem?

Comment: What @GhostKeeper is suggesting is a very rudimentary (and invasive) hack. I would advise against modifying any of your code. Like others have already said: a "Code Coverage" tool is what you're looking for. In Eclipse, select Help > Eclipse MarketPlace... then search for "eclemma", hit go, click the install button and proceed with the wizard. Once it's installed, you'll be able to right click on a unit test (or tests) and select "Coverage As..." instead of "Run As...". Executed lines of code will be green, and non-executed lines will be red. You'll see. It's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Asaph! I already tried Eclemma. But the information that the tool gives us is not enough to solve my problem getting coverage of a certain line of a test, not coverage of a test. As you know, A test can consists of variables, method calls and assertions. I want to get coverage of each method call in the test case.

Comment: @Junghyun: I think you've misunderstood the EclEmma tool. As we've said at least twice already, EclEmma *does* give you line level coverage information, _not_ block level. If you're observing that EclEmma turned an entire block of code green, that means it executed 100% of the lines in that block. Make sense?

Comment: @Aspah I updated the question. I hope this makes you understand my purpose.

Comment: Your tests seem to be constructed oddly.  You probably shouldn't have more than one call to `acct1.executeTransaction(...)`.  Also, the comment there doesn't appear to match the assertions.  If you can limit the number of methods called per test, then what you want shows up as a side effect.

Answer (score 2):

I will absolutely go with Eclemma, you can add it as plugin in eclipse, just go in help->install new software and then use this link in the Work with space:

http://update.eclemma.org/

you then will be able to check the coverage of your unit test, simple but absolutely necessary, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi! Eclemma just shows coverage of a test case, not coverage of a specific line of the test case. Is there any way to get the covered methods for a specific line of a junit test?

Comment: @Junghyun: Eclemma *does* show you line level granularity. If all lines turn green, it means they've all been executed. Red lines were not executed, and yellow lines were partially executed.

Comment: @Asaph Yes. Green lines are covered lines. But the lines are covered lines for all statements in a test, not a specific statement in the test.

Comment: @Junghyun: You must be looking at the roll up data. Try looking at the actual source code to the test. Then you'll see what we've been saying: coverage data at the *line* level.

Comment: @Asaph I updated my question to be more clear. Can eclemma distinguish covered lines of a statement in a test and ones of another statement in the test?

Comment: @Junghyun: Break up your test method into multiple test methods and then just run one of the methods. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Asaph Yes. I thought about that. I expect there might be a better technique rather than breaking a test into multiple tests, though. Maybe I should use Eclipse AST to edit test on runtime. Thanks!